# Do we have to remove target variable from data in Scikit-learn's linearmodel.fit()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Scikit-learn's documentation says there are two arguments to the function: X(data) and y(Target Values). Do we remove the target variable from our data and provide it separately as y? Or do we keep target variable in X and also provide it separately as y? I have come across both approaches and was wondering which was correct.

Comment: Have you tried running your code and data either way? That should quickly show with a simple example.

Comment: I did a fair amount of research but couldn't find the answer.I know they're different, and the first approach seems to be correct, but nobody corrects the person who uses the second approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `X` should not contain the target as one of the columns. If you include it your linear model will produce no *coding* errors, but to predict the target `y` it will just use the feature `y`.

Comment: These were my thoughts exactly, but I've come across some tutorials and kernels on kaggle where the target is not removed from X. One kernel where I couldn't find where this step was done [link](https://www.kaggle.com/jaganath/advanced-regression-techniques-explained-eda)

Answer (score 1):

To my understand, you shouldn't predict tomorrow's weather by tomorrow's weather. If you already know what's the correct value, it is pointless to predict one.

However, you don't need to remove target variable in your dataset either, just don't include it in your X-axis.

What we are trying to do with a predictive model? Based on past records(both x and y), we trained our model to find their relationships. In future, we may no longer have y, but we still have x in our hands, assuming their relationship doesn't change, we predict what is the y for the future.